# Reference request: for a proof of a reflection [from transitive sets] based axiomatization of ZF\Reg.?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

The following system is quoted from Harvey Friedman's lecture notes. The language is first order logic with membership $\in$.

*Axioms:*

1. **Extensionality.** $(\forall x)(x \in  y \leftrightarrow x \in  z) \to (\forall x)(y \in x \leftrightarrow z \in x).$
2. **Pairing.** $(\exists x)(y,z \in  x).$
3. **Union.** $(\exists x)(\forall y \in  w)(\forall z \in  y)(z \in  x).$
4. **Separation.** $(\exists x)(\forall y)(y \in  x \leftrightarrow (y \in  z \land \varphi))$, where $\varphi$ is a formula in $L(\in )$ in which $x$ is not free.
5. **Power set.** $(\exists x)(\forall y)(y \subseteq z \to y \in  x).$
6. **Reflection.** $(\exists  \ transitive \ x)(y_1,…,y_n \in  x \land (\forall z_1,…,z_m \in  x)((\exists w)(\varphi) \to (\exists w \in  x)(\varphi)))$, where $m,n \geq 1$ and $\varphi$ is a formula in $L(\in )$ whose free variables are among $y_1,…,y_n,z_1,…,z_m,w.$
7. **Infinity.** $(\exists x)(\emptyset \in  x \land (\forall y \in  x)(y \cup \{y\} \in  x)).$

This system is equivalent to $\small \sf ZF\setminus Reg.$ according to H. Friedman. However in his [lecture notes](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/TalkAxiomSetThy-ts05xn.pdf) he didn't cite a reference to that result.

> Question: Where can I find a proof of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a result I used in a paper I am working on.

Let $M$ reflect $\exists x(x\in X\land\phi(x,y))$ (In this case $\phi(x,y)↔y=f(x)$). Then $\{y│(M,∈)\vDash\exists x(x\in X\land\phi(x,y))\}=\{y│\exists x(x\in X\land\phi(x,y))\}\cap M$ and $\{y│\exists x(x\in X\land\phi(x,y))\}\cap M=\{y│\exists x(x ∈ X\land\phi(x,y))\}$. Therefore $\{y│\exists x(x ∈ X\land\phi(x,y))\}\subseteq M$. By separation then $\{y│\exists x(x ∈ X\land\phi(x,y))\}$ is a set.